# How to filter valueerror exception for only string or float values

Tags: python, string, char, try-except

Im doing a school project and my teacher asked me this:
"If the user enters data of type string or float it should appear the respective
message:

ERROR!! Inserted a value of type String or Char
ERROR!! Inserted a value of type float"

How can i do this?
btw i cant you like functions,classes or objects

the full question is "deve criar instruções necessárias para que o programa leia N números inteiros e
determine a soma, a média, o maior e o menor desse conjunto de N valores.".

```
   `min=0
    max=0
    z=1
    soma=0
    media=0
    num1 = int(input("How much values did you want to use: "))
    for i in range(0,num1):
        try:
            n1=int(input("number: "))
        except ValueError:
                print('ERROR!! Inserted a value of type String or Char')
                print('ERROR!! Inserted a value of type float')
                n1=int(input("number: "))
        soma+=n1
        media =soma/num1
        if z==1:
            max = min = n1
            z=2
        else:
            if n1 > max:
                max = n1
            if n1 < min:
                min = n1`
```

Comment: Please ask these kind of questions and assignments on Code review website: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Catching a `ValueError` is not really valuable here, as `int(1.222)` is valid and `int('99')` is also valid.

A `ValueError` *is* raised when your try `int('1.999')`, but to me, this is a string first and string/float second.

Perhaps you could introduce a `while` loop that waits for valid user input, and test the user input with `isinstance(...)`.

Example:

```
n1 = None

while(n1 is None): 

    user_input = input('Number: ')

    if isinstance(user_input, str): 
        print ('STRING ERROR!')
        continue # restart the loop

    if isinstance(user_input, float): 
        print ('FLOAT ERROR!')
        continue # restart the loop

    try: 
        n1 = int(user_input)
    except ValueError as e:
        # Something crazy happened
        print(e.message)
        continue # restart the loop

# Do the rest of the program
```

In addition, this `while` loop is able to handle multiple failed inputs, whereas

```
    try:
        n1=int(input("number: "))
    except ValueError:
            print('ERROR!! Inserted a value of type String or Char')
            print('ERROR!! Inserted a value of type float')
            n1=int(input("number: "))
```

will crash is you enter '1.999' twice.

Comment: i got the ValueError.

Comment: You got the `ValueError` when you did what?